# How do I install ruby 1.9.3-p429 using rbenv?

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I tried to install ruby 1.9.3-p429 using rbenv as follows; 
(on Ubuntu linux 12.04)

```
% git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git /path/to/rbenv 
% ln -s /path/to/rbenv ~/.rbenv 
% cd ~/.rbenv 
% echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshenv 
% echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshenv 
% exec $SHELL -l 
% git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

But, ruby-build dumps error message.

```
% rbenv install 1.9.3-p429 
Downloading yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz... 
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/36c852831d02cf90508c29852361d01b
-> http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20130701184855.7206
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20130701184855.7206.log

Last 10 log lines:


checksum mismatch: yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz (file is corrupt)
expected 36c852831d02cf90508c29852361d01b, got 956baf72fd20659d7045498cc3954bf2 : -q

curl: (33) HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume.

checksum mismatch: yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz (file is corrupt)
expected 36c852831d02cf90508c29852361d01b, got 956baf72fd20659d7045498cc3954bf2 : -q
```

What should I do about this trouble?

Comment: I already have tried again. but everytime fail to download. It seems that checksum mismatch occurs on downloading tarball.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had created shellscript named 'md5' in $HOME/bin , so It caused an incorrect action.

(Please refer ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin/ruby-build compute_md5() )

It's all my fault.

Finally I success 'rbenv install 1.9.3-p429'.